# Convert select2 dropdown from single select to multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have 10 to 12 select2 dropdowns in complex control, they need to be initialized as select2 dropdown.
**On dropdown-open**, I make ajax call to load data. The problem comes here, if there are specific data loaded from the server. the drop-down should became multiple select2.

Here is a part of the code:

```
$selectDropDown.select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '/GetValues',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            var query = {
                title: name,
            }

            return query;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            if (data.type === '10') {

               // I need to make it multiple select here
               return {results: data.results};
            } else {
               var values = getDefaultDataItems();
               return {results: values };
            }

        }
    },
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'Select values'
    width: '100%',
});
```

The data cannot be loaded before initialization of select2, because of optimization reasons.

Currently it works like:

```
 processResults: function (data) {
            if (data.type === '10') {

               // The hacking way
               $selectDropDown.select2({
                        multiple: 'multiple',
                        data: data.results
                    }).select2('open');
            } else {
               var values = getDefaultDataItems();
               return {results: values };
            }
        }
```

I want to ask it it he best way to do it?
Is there a build-in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way to do that is add attribute `multiple` to my `select`. And change attribute name become array. After that, call `.select2();` on my `select`.

For example, I have `select` with `sub-type` class.

```
$('.sub-type').prop('multiple', true).attr('name', 'sub_type[]').select2();
```

If you want back to single select again, just write this:

```
$('.sub-type').prop('multiple', false).attr('name', 'sub_type').select2();
```

Sorry for the late reply, I just found your question today. I hope my answer can help others.